# lyx and texlive 2012 in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: lyx, texlive, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 and installed texlive 2012. I was using TEXMAKER and it was nice to use.

Meanwhile I want to try to use Lyx. I installed version 2.00 of Lyx. When I compile simple document in Lyx I get nice output. 
But when I check the version of texlive, it says 2009/Debian.

I wonder if I can get some help on tuning Lyx so that it use version 2012 rather than 2009 during compilation.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: There should be settings by which you can declare the binaries used.

Comment: Ubuntu 11.10 is unsupported. Upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LyX` just runs "pdflatex yourfile.tex" so this is not a `LyX` issue. This is a path issue. To use TeX Live 2012 you need the binaries to be found before the 2009 binaries. So export your PATH (e.g. in your /etc/profile) so that this is true. To see what your path currently is, run `echo $PATH`. Also `which` and `type` will be useful for you. e.g. `which pdflatex`.